# How much types of User account in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, users

types of Users in Kali Linux and their function. How to login with kali Linux os system. tell me its command lines.

Comment: This question is super vague. What research have you done, yourself?

Comment: Install Kali in a VM and teach yourself what Kali is about.  Posted from my Kali 2023.2 mahcine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As any Linux distribution, Kali comes with arguably 3 types of accounts:

- `root`, which is superuser on the system and can do anything.
- User accounts, for individual users
- System/service accounts, for running system services

The last two are essentially the same "type", but just used for a different purpose.

Default credentials for Kali are:

```
Username: kali
Password: kali
```

If you haven't already, you might want to review [this](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/):

> As the distribution’s developers, you might expect us to recommend that everyone should be using Kali Linux. The fact of the matter is, however, that Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.